# populating a spinner items with multiple lines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Some items in my spinner are long and I would like the spinner to wrap the text over multiple lines depending on how long the text is. I looked over serval solutions for this but they are not working for me.

Here showing the text not fitting:

[image]

Here is my code in Java:

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner3() {

        spinner3D = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activities1);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Academic Year Opening Program");
        list.add("Academic Year Closing Program");
        list.add("LR1: Defining Primary Care, Health Care Disparities & Vulnerable Populations");
        list.add("LR2: Community Resources and the Elderly");
        list.add("LR3: Inter-professional Teams and the Homeless");
        list.add("LR4: Quality Improvement and Veterans");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.multiline_spinner_row, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_row);
        spinner3D.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

I created a custom row called "multiline_spinner_row.xml" where singleline is changed to false:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

All this does is make my selection wrap the text but not the items:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in spinner set this property:

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

in text view set these properties:

```
android:layout_weight="1"  
android:ellipsize="none"  
android:maxLines="100"  
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

Comment: We want a dropdown list, not a popup list dialog

Answer (score 2):

This actually worked for me (in Xamarin Android, but the problem is the same):

Instead of

```
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
```

write

```
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1);
```

Answer (score 1):

create an xml file like this, your xml will need to have a parent layout to wrap the TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    tools:text="123" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

make sure your TextView has an id, then create your adapter like this.

```
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.spinner_textview, R.id.textView, displayTexts);
```

use this consturctor

```
public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
        @IdRes int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<T> objects) {
    this(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects, false);
}
```

or any constructor that has textViewResourceId as a parameter

that's it. you won't need to override anything else.
Check out the below image to view the effect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwwax.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lISlk.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

I solved the problem with simple coding.

Just add Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1 when assigning the Adapter for Spinner as displayed below.

please check more on [My Blog Post](https://notostuck.blogspot.com/2020/08/how-to-populating-spinner-items-with.html)

Comment: Please elaborate a bit and try to avoid just pasting plain URLs in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
```